# How I can check if I lose connection with mqtt broker?

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

I am trying with [paho](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang) pkg to build mqtt sub client by golang,
and I have a problem with my client when the broker disconnect, I think should lost message [appear](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/options.go#L100), but this not happen, and if I start the broker, 
mqtt sub client can't able to get message sent by mqtt pub client.

why this happens and how I can fix that?

Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    mqtt "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)

var (
    broker                     = "tcp://localhost:1883"
    f      mqtt.MessageHandler = func(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
        fmt.Printf("TOPIC: %s\n", msg.Topic())
        fmt.Printf("MSG: %s\n", msg.Payload())
    }
)

func main() {
    //create a ClientOptions
    opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions().AddBroker(broker)
    opts.SetClientID("group-one")
    opts.SetDefaultPublishHandler(f)

    //create and start a client using the above ClientOptions
    c := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
    if token := c.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }

    if token := c.Subscribe("test", 0, nil); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        fmt.Println(token.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assign a custom `OnConnectionLostHandler` to catch connection lost event, so you can perform additional action whenever the client loses connection. If you set the `AutoReconnect` option to `true` (which is the default behavior), the client will automatically reconnects to the broker after connection lost. Please note that after connection lost, your subscription state/info may not being saved by the broker, so you won't be able to receive any message. To deal with this issue, move topic subscription to `OnConnect` handler. Below is an example implementation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    mqtt "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)

func messageHandler(c mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
    fmt.Printf("TOPIC: %s\n", msg.Topic())
    fmt.Printf("MSG: %s\n", msg.Payload())
}

func connLostHandler(c mqtt.Client, err error) {
    fmt.Printf("Connection lost, reason: %v\n", err)

    //Perform additional action...
}

func main() {
    //create a ClientOptions
    opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions().
        AddBroker("tcp://localhost:1883").
        SetClientID("group-one").
        SetDefaultPublishHandler(messageHandler).
        SetConnectionLostHandler(connLostHandler)

    //set OnConnect handler as anonymous function
    //after connected, subscribe to topic
    opts.OnConnect = func(c mqtt.Client) {
        fmt.Printf("Client connected, subscribing to: test/topic\n")

        //Subscribe here, otherwise after connection lost, 
        //you may not receive any message
        if token := c.Subscribe("test/topic", 0, nil); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
            fmt.Println(token.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }

    //create and start a client using the above ClientOptions
    c := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
    if token := c.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }

    for {
        //Lazy...
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but I think  [OnConnectionLostHandler](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/options.go#L100) by default must notify me I lost connection!!!

Comment: The default handler just print the message (My bad, the example above also just print a message ...). I means, if you assign a custom connection lost handler, you can do more than just printing a message, e.g. counting the number of connection lost, send notification through email, etc...

Comment: `OnConnectionLostHandler` not print any thing if I lost connection.

Comment: To see the message, you need to setup `DEBUG` handler, e.g. add `mqtt.DEBUG = log.New(os.Stderr, "DEBUG    ", log.Ltime)` to the first line of your `main` function.

Comment: This should be in the default sample of paho - the fact that one must re-subscribe after a disconnect event is quite surprising.